# JavaScript setTimeout and setInterval

Tags: javascript, html

I have three divs which should appear one at a time infinitly. i needed 2 seconds interval between the visibility change. here's what i have come up with. but it didn't work. please help me make it work

```
var taglines = document.getElementsByClassName("tagline");
taglines[0].style.color = 'red';
setInterval(function () {
taglines[1].style.visibility = 'hidden';
taglines[2].style.visibility = 'hidden';
    setTimeout(function () {
        taglines[1].style.visibility = 'visible';
        taglines[0].style.visibility = 'hidden';
        taglines[2].style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }, 2000);
    setTimeout(function () {
        taglines[2].style.visibility = 'visible';
        taglines[0].style.visibility = 'hidden';
        taglines[1].style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }, 4000);
}, 5000);
```

Comment: *"but it didn't work"* *How* did it not work? What exactly is the problem? The more you explain, the easier it is for us to help you.

Comment: Ya know… I think this can be done with CSS animation… no javascript needed.  It's much more efficient, though a bit less compatible - http://caniuse.com/css-animation

Comment: the intervals at which visibility change occurs is not correct. i want a fluid transition, like 1st div-2 seconds-2nd div-2 second-3rd div and this should happen indefinitly.

Comment: Are you sure you wouldn't rather use CSS to do this?

Comment: yes, i know css delays and transition.

Comment: but haven't yet given a thought about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend CSS, but if you really wanted to do javaScript, you would do it something like this

```
var taglines = document.getElementsByClassName("tagline");
curTag = 0;

setInterval(function(){
    taglines[curTag].style.visibility = 'hidden';
    curTag++;
    if (curTag==3) { curTag=0;}
    taglines[curTag].style.visibility = 'visible';
},2000);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fPDfv/